# How do I store each value in a string?

Tags: c++, string

I am aware that this code is iterating through and getting the data from the file but I want to store each value in it's own independent string.

```
int getHosts()
{
    system("clear");
    GfdOogleTech gfd;
    string data = gfd.GetFileContents("./vhosts.a2m");
    size_t cPos = 0
    string currentValue;
    while( currentValue.assign(gfd.rawParse(data, "|", "|", &cPos)) != blank )
    {
         cout << currentValue << endl;
    }
    system("sleep 5");
    return 0;
}
```

The code above outputs the following values:

- crativetech.me.conf
- www.creativetech.me
- webmaster@creativetech.me
- /web/creativetech/www

How do I store each one of the above values in it's own string?

Comment: Simply declare a std::vector<std::string> before the while loop and pushback currentValue in it? Unless I am missing something terribly obvious :S

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer would be with a `std::vector<std::string>`, something like this:

```
string currentValue;
std::vector<std::string> addresses;

while( currentValue.assign(gfd.rawParse(data, "|", "|", &cPos)) != blank )
     addresses.push_back(currentValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a vector of strings, add each new entry to the end.

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
strings.push_back(current_value);
```